# What does F.O. mean, and is it related to a repeat?

Tags: notation, sheet-music, repeats

I have some sheet music (from a Japanese book, if that matters in any way) and it says "F.O." at the end of some pieces.

I could find some other terms related to repeats (D.S. being Dal Segno, so D.S. to A makes sense to me), but I couldn't find "F.O." mentioned anywhere.

[image: Sheet Music F.O.]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

F.O. = "Fade Out".

In the first case, for example, it means that after the D.S., once arriving at A, fade out rather than complete the section.

In the second case, allowing the repeat covers only a few bars (4–8, say), it means to keep repeating until ultimately fading into nothing.

Comment: Thanks, that makes perfect sense (It's Sheet Music for a video game, in this case Chrono Trigger, so repeating and fading out makes perfect sense)

Comment: You might also encounter R.T.F over a repeated section.   Repeat To Fade.

Comment: Oh, so F.O. doesn't mean Eff Off? I thought it meant that due to the ending music repeating ad nauseam.

Comment: @Dekkadeci  no, that would be  "F.T.F.O"  :-)

Comment: @Dekkadeci To be fair, [it is a beautiful piece](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4D_VgtgYKfg) :)